# Unable to start blueprint container - Hello World

Tags: osgi, karaf, sdn, opendaylight

I'm new in Opendaylight and I was following a tutorial to build a simple Hello World project ([this tutorial](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/OpenDaylight_Controller:MD-SAL:Startup_Project_Archetype#Part_2_-_Hello_World_-_Defining_a_Simple_RPC)) but when I run the project with `./karaf` and check if the module is initialized with `log:display | grep hello` I obtain this error:

```
2017-08-04 12:43:57,159 | INFO  | Event Dispatcher | YangTextSchemaContextResolver    | 55 - org.opendaylight.yangtools.yang-parser-impl - 1.0.2.Boron-SR2 | Provided module name /META-INF/yang/hello.yang@0000-00-00.yang does not match actual text hello@2015-01-05.yang, corrected
2017-08-04 12:44:01,928 | INFO  | Event Dispatcher | YangTextSchemaContextResolver    | 55 - org.opendaylight.yangtools.yang-parser-impl - 1.0.2.Boron-SR2 | Provided module name /META-INF/yang/hello.yang@0000-00-00.yang does not match actual text hello@2015-01-05.yang, corrected
2017-08-04 12:44:08,295 | INFO  | Event Dispatcher | BlueprintBundleTracker           | 148 - org.opendaylight.controller.blueprint - 0.5.2.Boron-SR2 | Creating blueprint container for bundle org.opendaylight.hello.impl_0.1.0.SNAPSHOT [174] with paths [bundleentry://174.fwk592688102/org/opendaylight/blueprint/impl-blueprint.xml]
2017-08-04 12:44:08,318 | ERROR | Event Dispatcher | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 15 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.6.1 | Unable to start blueprint container for bundle org.opendaylight.hello.impl/0.1.0.SNAPSHOT
```

With the `diag` command I get this output:

```
opendaylight-user@root>diag
hello-impl (174)
----------------
Status: Failure
Blueprint
4/08/17 14:12
Exception: 
Unable to validate xml
org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Unable to validate xml
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.parser.Parser.validate(Parser.java:349)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.parser.Parser.validate(Parser.java:336)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.doRun(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:343)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:276)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:300)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:269)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.access$900(BlueprintExtender.java:68)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender$BlueprintContainerServiceImpl.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:602)
    at org.opendaylight.controller.blueprint.BlueprintBundleTracker.modifiedBundle(BlueprintBundleTracker.java:178)
    at org.opendaylight.controller.blueprint.BlueprintBundleTracker.addingBundle(BlueprintBundleTracker.java:159)
    at org.opendaylight.controller.blueprint.BlueprintBundleTracker.addingBundle(BlueprintBundleTracker.java:51)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:467)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:414)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:229)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleTracker.java:443)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:847)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.publishBundleEventPrivileged(Framework.java:1568)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.publishBundleEvent(Framework.java:1504)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.publishBundleEvent(Framework.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'blueprint' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.elementLocallyValidComplexType(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.elementLocallyValidType(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processElementContent(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.DOMValidatorHelper.finishNode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.DOMValidatorHelper.validate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.DOMValidatorHelper.validate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.ValidatorImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.validation.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.parser.Parser.validate(Parser.java:346)
    ... 32 more
```

As I've said, I was following the tutorial so my files are exactly the same to the opendaylight link (this is the repository I've created [GitHub](http://github.com/Onishima/opendaylight_test)).

I think it's important to say how I've generated. This is de code:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.opendaylight.controller -DarchetypeArtifactId=opendaylight-startup-archetype -DarchetypeRepository=https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/public/ -DarchetypeCatalog=remote -DarchetypeVersion=1.2.2-Boron-SR2
```

Thank you all,

Daniel Romero Morcillo

Comment: Is that all error details you have? Try the diag command. Maybe you get some more details. You can also try to put some logging statements in you code to see where it fails.

Comment: I've added new information about the errors. I'm sorry but I don't have a deep knowledge about Opendaylight so I would need some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the logs you provided:

```
Element 'blueprint' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.
```

So I think there are simply some errors (invalid XML) in your blueprint file.

If it is exactly like the one in the link you provided [[here]](https://github.com/Onishima/opendaylight_test/blob/master/impl/src/main/resources/org/opendaylight/blueprint/impl-blueprint.xml#L19) there are some extra characters in line 19

Comment: Man, I'm such an idiot. I spent a lot of time checking for this kind of errors. I needed one more pair of eyes. Thanks!